# Confused about how to get data in register at auth ui

Tags: laravel

I am still confused as to how I fixed this so can someone explain it to me?
So I am new at laravel and I am using that auth scaffolding thing? So this is where I got confused. I added this extra div on register form to give roles.

```
<div class="row mb-3">
    <label for="select-role" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Select Role')}}</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select id="role" class="form-control" name="role">
            <option value="admin">Admin</option>
            <option value="manager">Manager</option>
            <option value="cashier">Cashier</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is where I am confused about. I don't know how I put the value of the select tag in this function of the RegisterController.

```
protected function create(array $data) <-- this is where I'm confused
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'role' => $data['role'],
    ]);
}
```

I don't know how I passed the role value to the `(array $data)` is the `$data['x']` x = referring to id, or name of the select tag?

Comment: which Auth Scaffolding you are using ?

Comment: It should be vue? I just used php artisan ui:auth. And I installed react before that if that is relevant.

Comment: see my answer below, it should help you.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment above, it seems your are using `Laravel UI` as the Auth Scaffolding.
Am not familiar with `Laravel UI` (actually, all of the scaffolding available) but with some digging in the source code of `Laravel UI` here's a way to get things done.

1. In `validator` method, under `RegisterController`, add the new field, you called it `role`, to the data being validated. You'll end up with something similar to this:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
  return Validator::make($data, [
    'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
    'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    /** add the "role" field so it gets validated as well */
    'role' => ['required', 'in:admin,manager,cashier'] /** just an example of rules for the sake of the demo */
  ]);
}
```

2. Now, in the `create` method of the `RegisterController` you'll have access to the new `role` field as `$data['role']` which you can pass to the `create` method of the `Users` model like so:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
  return User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    /** save the "role" along the other data */
    'role' => $data['role']
  ]);
}
```

3. Now, upon registering new users, the `role` field is required to be selected and once the validation passes, the created user will have a `role` attribue just like the `name`, `email` and `password` attributes.

> The demo above **assumes** that your Database is correctly configured and it has a table called `users` that by its own have a field called `role`.

Comment: I mean to say how did I pass the Select tag with the name of role to the **array $data** at the Register Control. That **$data['role']**, did it take the **name** of the tag or the **Id**?

Comment: @RONALDOJR.ARNIBAL it takes the name. In your case, the new field is called `role`. All form fields are sent to the server with their `name` attributes.